# Set Custom Validation for File Upload in angular Form is not working as expected

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, angular10, pdf.js

I want to implement upload pdf file validation. If uploaded pdf file is password protected then it should not be allowed. I am using angular typescript.

**Below is My Custom Validation Function**

```
export function pdfFileValidator(file: File,fileExtension:string): AsyncValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<{ [key: string]: any } | null> => {
    var res = false;
    if(fileExtension.toLowerCase() === 'pdf'){
        pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = 'pdf.worker.js'
        var url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        const loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument(url);
        loadingTask.promise.then(function(pdf) {console.error(pdf)})
        .catch((e:PasswordException) => {
            console.error("File is Password Protected")
            res = true;
        }).finally( ()  =>{
            return {
                'EncryptedFileViolated': res,
            }; 
        });
    }
    console.error("response =",res)
    return of(null);
    };
}
```

**Below is my set Validation function**

```
setFileValidators(fileSize: number, fileExtension: string,file:File) {
        this.form.get('file')?.setValidators([FileSizeValidator(fileSize, this.maxSizeAllowedInMB),
FileExtensionValidator(fileExtension, ['pdf','jpg','png'])]);
this.form.get('file')?.addAsyncValidators(pdfFileValidator(file,fileExtension));
        this.form.get('file')!.updateValueAndValidity()
        console.error(this.form);
      }
```

**How It is working now**

these two lines executed earlier without waiting for the complete execution of the `pdfFileValidator` function

```
  this.form.get('file')!.updateValueAndValidity()
  console.error(this.form);
```

And Form shows `status = valid`

I want `this.form.get('file')?.addAsyncValidators()` should wait for completion of `pdfFileValidator()` function and after that execute `updateValueAndValidity()` function.

How we can implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You pdfJs library function is taking time and you have set synchronous validation with `setValidators` function and due to this its not working as you want.

You have to set asynchronous validators with [setasyncvalidators](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#setasyncvalidators)

Comment: I tried `export function pdfFileValidator(file: File,fileExtension:string): AsyncValidatorFn {  return (control: AbstractControl):Observable<{ [key: string]: any } | null>  => {  --same code --};}` and for set validation `this.form.get('file')?.addAsyncValidators(pdfFileValidator(file,fileExtension));` but it still works same